# Storing data MySQL in Kurdish font?

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

Hi so I've made an application in java that lets the user to store data in a MySQL database. Whenever I enter this به‌رواری ده‌رچوون I just get ??????. Is there any way I can fix that? It's really important that this job is done before tomorrow... I've never faced a problem such as this, and now I'm creating a database app for a company in Kurdistan, and now my friend asked, well does it store data with their characters? Heart attack! Please help!

I'm using PhpMyadmin on a localhost computer using XAMPP

Comment: are you using unicode? are you storing and reading your data with the proper character encoding?

Comment: What is proper character encoding? And yes I am using UTF8_Unicode_ci

Comment: I mean that you must be consistent with the encoding when reading and writing. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html) says that mysql 5.0 supports those arabic characters.

Comment: please post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing this behaviour, and the create statement of your table.

Comment: Okay I just managed to make my mysql database capable of handling kurdish characters, but there is still a problem. Whenever I try to add new data via phpmyadmin there seem to be no problem but with my java application which I have built there is.

Comment: @1010 Do you have any clue?

Comment: @BK435 Or do you have any clue?

Comment: Post a new question for the Java issue. Include code samples where you configure/open the connection to the database. Issue will 10-1 be the same: non matching encodings.

Comment: @DaroanAdnan not without seeing any code.

Comment: check [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arabic+mysql+java), some of them seem to be a similar problem.

Comment: @1010 - since there are at least 4 different ways to screw up with `CHARACTER SET`, your link to "these questions" should be further filtered down to "????" cases.  In particular the first one (`Ø§Ø¨Ùˆ Ù†Øµ`) would wrongly imply that the garbled text can be converted back to the right text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened:

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

As you `INSERTed` the data, it was converted to latin1, which does not have values for Arabic (Kurdish/Farsi/etc) characters, so question marks replaced them.

The cure (for future `INSERTs`):

- utf8-encoded data (good)
- `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')` (or whatever your client needs for establishing the `CHARACTER SET`)
- check that the column(s) and/or table default are `CHARACTER SET utf8`
- If you are displaying on a web page, `<meta...utf8>` should be near the top.

The discussion above is about `CHARACTER SET`, the encoding of characters.  Now for a tip on `COLLATION`, which is used for comparing and sorting.

To double check that the data is stored correctly, do
`SELECT col, HEX(col)...`.
`ه‌رچوون` should come back `D987E2808CD8B1DA86D988D988D986`
Arabic characters in utf8 have hex of D8xx or D9xx.

(`utf8mb4` works just as well as `utf8`; either works for Arabic.)

Bad news:  The data that was inserted and turned into '???' cannot be recovered.

Comment: There is one problem though, I have the COLLATION of the mysql server the same as the data stored in the tables. utf8mb4 that would say, but I can't compare strings of 4 bytes, only 3...

Comment: Each Arabic _character_ occupies 2 _bytes_.  `D987` is hex for 2 bytes.  If the `CHARACTER SET` is `utf8`, use `COLLATION utf8_unicode_ci`.  for `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, use `COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

put the below code in the `connection` PHP file then set collation in phpmyadmin (mysql) to utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci:

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$databasename="ab1";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("connection failed" .$conn->connect_error);
}else
echo "connection sucssessfullly";
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
?>
```